# Android Phonegap show first Activity till Second Activity is fully loaded

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on Android and Cordova 2.9 (a Hybrid Application). I am facing a problem while i am switching from one Activity to another. When the application is switching from one activity to another a white screen appears. This white screen is the background color of the Cordova. Our requirement is such that this white screen should not appear.The first activity should remain until the second activity is fully loaded.After the second Activity is fully loaded (along with the html content) then only should it be displayed. Following the working code:-

**FirstActivity**

```
public class FirstActivity extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(this,"axismf");
        // super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());        
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/goalTimeline.html");        
    }

    public void loadSecondActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);        
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Second Activity","Second Activity Loaded");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
         super.init();       
         //super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
         super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/goalChildEdu.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```